# Implement Google speech credentials with API key or Service accounts

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I have a question regarding implementing Google speech, or google cloud API in general, for Android

What I want is to have multiple certificates or API keys for different clients.
In practice, I can have 10 different Android devices, linked to Server 1 for Client 1, and 20 different Android devices, linked to another server for Client 2.
I would like to split the billing of this clients but using same Android project/package.

In https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech example there is an OAuth2 Credential used, but the problem here is that you can have only 1 OAuth2 Credential for 1 project, but in this case I would need multiple, so this is not an option.

Even if I implement OAuth2 on a server and refresh Tokens for devices, I would need to have multiples.

In the end I would have 1 google account, with multiple client configuration, where each client is seperate when checking billing info and also for restricting purposes. If I have multiple keys I can just disable one and that is

So my question is (if I can split billing for specific API key/service account, or just know the usage used)

1. How to change example implementation to use API keys or different Service accounts with GoogleCredentials.fromstream()? Do I need to manually implement API requests to google REST API, or is this possible in Android with something like:

   ```
   SpeechClient.create(SpeechSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider {API_KEY}.build())
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have billing details per API Keys used on Speech API. Here, the easiest solution is to have one project per customer. When a request come in, check the user Id (because the user is already authenticated and you have a OAuth2 token) on the server and, according with the user info stored somewhere (we use Firestore for user profile storage), call the Speech API in the correct project.

You have 1 billing per project, and a free tier per project also!

---

**Edit 1**

It's possible I wasn't clear. Here a schema.

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you! But I don't think I can create multiple projects with same Android SHA1 key, because only one project can have it?

Comment: I don't know the android world. But, from my point of view, your android app will connect to only one project, the main one with the dispatch process (and the firestore database to know at which customer belong the user and the project to call). Only the Speech APIs are used in the other project, and it's your main process which call them.

Comment: The thing is that I have setup project as my Android application and in that project I have SHA1 key, that is used to verify the app. You can only have 1 project with 1 SHA1 key, so having multiple is not an option

Comment: I added a schema. Is it better? suitable?

Comment: If I go through:
1. I have created new project -> GeneralProject. This project has Android OAuth2 credential, which is linked to my SHA1 from Android project, so I can only have 1 project with this OAuth and all devices can have this 1 OAuth2.json file. I cannot create Project 2 with same auth.
2. I download .json run Google speech api with this Key.
3. I know on device for which Client it is, so I don't need additional firestore database? So device knows some random ID for a client
I don't know how can you create multiple "sub" projects then, from this General projects and link them?

Comment: I think I found the solution...
I can generate service account for each project and download certificate.json key. The problem is that you cannot redownload same file, but need to create new key (I think)
I can also use 1 project with multiple service keys, but I need to check if I can split billing then.
Thank you anway!

Comment: Why do you need service account key files? Where will you use them?

Comment: I don't know how to create a dispatch process from General Project to new Projects, so I will create different Service keys, which are not bound to Android application package but are bound to seperate projects I can create. This Service keys, I can download 1 for Project 1 as Json and use them on Client 1, and for other I can create new Projects, create Service accounts on them and use them on that Client.